Ionic app build error after upgrading Node from v16 to v18
After upgrading to node v18.19.1 globally I am now getting this error trying to run "ionic serve".
Using Angular 12 and ionic/angular 6.4.2.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
I'm thinking I might just move back to node 16 until I am ready to update all my packages to the latest version.
My package.json is quite large so I have not added it, but can add on request.
> > ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100 [ng] - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)... [ng]
> node:internal/crypto/hash:69 [ng]   this[kHandle] = new
> _Hash(algorithm, xofLen); [ng]                   ^ [ng] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported [ng]     at new
> Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19) [ng]     at Object.createHash
> (node:crypto:133:10) [ng]     at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory
> (R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:145:18)
> [ng]     at BulkUpdateDecorator.update
> (R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:46:50)
> [ng]     at SourceMapSource.updateHash
> (R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\SourceMapSource.js:231:8)
> [ng]     at NormalModule._initBuildHash
> (R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:880:17) [ng]     at handleParseResult
> (R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:946:10) [ng]     at
> R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:1040:4
> [ng]     at processResult
> (R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:755:11) [ng]     at
> R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:819:5
> [ng]     at
> R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:407:3
> [ng]     at iterateNormalLoaders
> (R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:10)
> [ng]     at iterateNormalLoaders
> (R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:240:10)
> [ng]     at
> R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:255:3
> [ng]     at context.callback
> (R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
> [ng]     at
> R:\myapp\myappApp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:71 {
> [ng]   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope
> routines::initialization error' ], [ng]   library: 'digital envelope
> routines', [ng]   reason: 'unsupported', [ng]   code:
> 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED' [ng] } [ng] Node.js v18.19.1
> 
> [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
> 
>         The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.


move back to node 16
